# node server project, browser can't connect, can't connect the port

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, centos, port

There is a node project about realtime chat, it runs fine locally, but can't run in the server（centOS7）,firewall is opened。

> node@16,14,0

Here is the project modules installed,and express listen (3000,'0.0.0.0')

> ├── bufferutil@4.0.1
> ├── express@4.17.3
> ├── moment@2.29.1
> ├── nodemon@2.0.15
> ├── socket.io@4.4.1
> └── utf-8-validate@5.0.2

And when I ask a 'telnet' the 3000 PORT at local, it can't connect the server.`telnet XX.XX.XX.XX 3000`;when I `netstat -ntpl` at the server,it shows the 3000 port is activing.

browser can't get resources, console:[No resource with given URL found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJHQs.jpg).

> crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

Comment: i'm a beginner about coding, i don't know if it's clear enough, the project is followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jD7FnbI76Hg

Comment: Please add code so that someone can help you easier.

Comment: if you are deploying on aws or similar IaaS, you should also have to enable the port in their firewall as well